# Why can't I count the number of models in a line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

This gives error back. I cannot find out what's wrong with this statement:(

```
@communitiies_count = user.get_up_voted Community.count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time you should probably post the error you are getting as well but I think what you want is this:

```
@communities_count = user.get_up_voted(Community).count
```